# Create SolidColorBrush with Windows 11 theme color

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to create a `SolidColorBrush` with Windows 11 theme color.

I'm able to use Windows 11's theme color directly, but cannot create a `SolidColorBrush`.

```
<!-- This works: -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground"
            Value="{x:Static SystemParameters.WindowGlassBrush}"/>
</Style>

<!-- This does not work: -->
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColor}" Color="Red"/>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a `SolidColorBrush` based on Windows theme color you could do it for example such way:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="scbr" 
                 Color="{Binding Color,
                 Source={x:Static SystemParameters.WindowGlassBrush}}" 
                 Opacity="{Binding Opacity,
                 Source={x:Static SystemParameters.WindowGlassBrush}}"
                 Transform="{Binding Transform,
                 Source={x:Static SystemParameters.WindowGlassBrush}}"/>
```